# Values getting lost in Qt Program with Classes output error

Tags: c++, qt, class, output

I've got a Qt Assignment that I just can't seem to get working.

Here's the assignment description:

> A product is described using a name, a price and a supplier.  The
>   supplier and the manufacturer can be the same for a product.
>
> A `Product` is initialised using a name and a price.  The supplier details are set using the function `setSupplier()`, which invokes the
>   suitable function of `Vendor` to set the details of the vendor.  If
>   one requests a product for its manufacturer, it returns the name of
>   the vendor stored in `m_Supplier`, if it is set as the manufacturer. 
>   Otherwise an `Unknown` string is returned. `toString()` of `Vendor`
>   returns a string representation of the values of its data members in a
>   readable format. `toString()` of `Product` always returns a string
>   representation of a product.  If `supplierDetails` in `toString()` of
>   `Product` is `true`, it returns both the supplier and product details.
>   Otherwise only product details are returned.
>
> Implement it as a console application, where the product and suuplier
>   details are entered from the keyboard.  Display the results of
>   `getManufacturerName()` and `toString()` (for both `true` and `false`
>   parameter values) on the console.

Unfortunately I really can't find out where I'm going wrong with this so I'll past all my code of all my files below in hopes that someone can spot where this is going wrong.

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "vendor.h"
#include "product.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>

QTextStream cout(stdout);
QTextStream cin(stdin);  

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    //Declare variables
    QString productName;
    QString productPriceStr;
    double productPrice;
    QString supplierName;
    QString supplierEmail;
    QString supplierIsManufacturerStr;
    bool supplierIsManufacturer;

    //Get user input
    cout << "Enter the product name:" << endl;
    productName = cin.readLine();
    cout << "Enter the product price:" << endl;
    productPriceStr = cin.readLine();
    cout << "Enter the supplier name:" << endl;
    supplierName = cin.readLine();
    cout << "Enter the supplier email:" << endl;
    supplierEmail = cin.readLine();
    cout <<"Is the supplier a manufacturer (y/n):\t" << endl;
    supplierIsManufacturerStr = cin.readLine();

    productPrice = productPriceStr.toDouble();

    if(supplierIsManufacturerStr.at(0).toLower() == 'y') {
        supplierIsManufacturer = true;
    } else {
        supplierIsManufacturer = false;
    }

    //Implement classes
    Vendor vendor;
    Product product(productName, productPrice, vendor);
    product.setSupplier(supplierName, supplierEmail, supplierIsManufacturer);

    cout << product.toString(supplierIsManufacturer) << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

product.h

```
#ifndef PRODUCT_H
#define PRODUCT_H

#include "vendor.h"
#include <QString>

class Product {
public:
    Product(QString name, double price, Vendor vendor);
    void setSupplier(QString name, QString email, bool isManufacturer);
    QString getManufacturerName();
    QString toString(bool SupplierDetails);
private:
    QString m_Name;
    double m_Price;
    Vendor m_Supplier;
};

#endif // PRODUCT_H
```

product.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include "product.h"
#include "vendor.h"

Product::Product(QString name, double price, Vendor vendor) {
        m_Name = name;
        m_Price = price;
        m_Supplier = vendor;
}

void Product::setSupplier(QString name, QString email, bool isManufacturer) {
    Vendor vendor;
    vendor.setDetails(name, email, isManufacturer);
}

QString Product::getManufacturerName() {
    if(m_Supplier.isManufacturer()) {
        return m_Supplier.getName();
    } else {
        return "Unknown";
    }
}

QString Product::toString(bool supplierDetails) {
    QString output;

    output = "\nProduct name:\t\t" + m_Name + "\nProduct price:\t\tR" + m_Price + "\nProduct Supplier:\t" + getManufacturerName();

    if(supplierDetails) {
        return m_Supplier.toString() + output;
    } else {
        return output;
    }
}
```

vendor.h

```
#ifndef VENDOR_H
#define VENDOR_H

#include <QString>

class Vendor {
public:
    Vendor();
    void setDetails(QString name, QString email, bool isManufacturer);
    bool isManufacturer();
    QString getName();
    QString toString();
private:
    QString m_Name;
    QString m_Email;
    bool m_IsManufacturer;
};

#endif // VENDOR_H
```

vendor.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include "vendor.h"

Vendor::Vendor() {

}

void Vendor::setDetails(QString name, QString email, bool isManufacturer) {
    m_Name = name;
    m_Email = email;
    m_IsManufacturer = isManufacturer;
}

bool Vendor::isManufacturer() {
    return m_IsManufacturer;
}

QString Vendor::getName() {
    return m_Name;
}

QString Vendor::toString() {
    QString output;
    QString manufacturerYesNo;

    if(m_IsManufacturer) {
        manufacturerYesNo = "Yes";
    } else {
        manufacturerYesNo = "No";
    }

    output = "\nVendor name:\t\t" + m_Name +  "\nVendor email:\t\t" + m_Email + "\nManufacturer:\t\t" + manufacturerYesNo;

    return output;
}
```

That's it.

There are no compiling errors, this is purely an algorithm error.  So far, whatever input I give it always displays only the product name and then sometimes a non-numerical value for product price and then everything else is empty.  The `toString()` function still seem to run though.

If anyone can see what's wrong you'd be a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what's wrong.  In my product.cpp file I made a new vendor in the setDetails function which left all my Vendor details blank.  I should have used the m_Supplier variable that I set as a parameter in the Product constructor...

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
 output = "\nProduct name:\t\t" + m_Name + "\nProduct price:\t\tR" + m_Price + "\nProduct Supplier:\t" + getManufacturerName();
```

Should be:

```
 output = "\nProduct name:\t\t" + m_Name + "\nProduct price:\t\tR" + QString::number(m_Price) + "\nProduct Supplier:\t" + getManufacturerName();
```

You should convert a number to QString before "+" them all.

And overload operator "=" in Vendor class

```
Vendor operator=(const Vendor& other)
{
  m_Name = other.m_Name;
  m_Email  = other.m_Email;
  m_IsManufacturer = other.m_IsManufacturer;

}
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the number issue but that the other field still aren't working :/

Comment: You should overload "=" in Vendor class.

Assign  m_Supplier = vendor; in the Product constructor may lead to undefined behavior

Comment: What do mean by that?

Comment: Vendor operator=(const Vendor& other)
    {
      m_Name = other.m_Name;
      m_Email  = other.m_Email;
      m_IsManufacturer = other.m_IsManufacturer;
   
    }

Comment: Gives an error stating: 'Vendor operator=(const Vendor&)' must be a nonstatic member function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71971/discussion-between-rain-and-barry-doyle).